# How do i find out if one of the last to buttons were clicked from a dynamic content list

Tags: jquery

I have like 8 of these div blocks and i want to know if the last two a in the list of 8 were clicked.  This will be dynamic so it could be 8 now and 20 later so the code needs to know that its the last two not if its 7 or 8.

```
<div class="seven columns offset-by-one">
  <h1>
    Joshua F. Schwartz
  </h1>
  <h2>
    Position
  </h2>
  <p>
    Etiam lacus dui, sollicitudin non pulvinar nec, fringilla commodo mauris. Nunc orci enim, pellentesque porta malesuada eu, ornare vel lectus. In venenatis nisl ut lorem ultricies semper. Duis vitae turpis nec tortor dignissim tempor. Phasellus et elit et. <a href="">Read More</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Comment: If they're dynamic, why not assign a dynamic class or ID to each `<a>` indicating which set of divs it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery index() method:

```
function isLastTwo(element) {
  // Get the total <div> tags
  var length = $("div.columns.offset-by-one").length;

  // Compare the index of current element to the length
  return $(element).index() >= (length - 2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just updated my answer. Thank you @Dogbert :D

Comment: Completely unnecessary. jQuery already provides index-based selectors like the one I commented about above.

Comment: I know the gt selector, @MattBall. But I don't think the code will be clear and easy to use in this situation. Furthermore, gt selector with negative index does not work in jQuery prior to 1.8. So be careful when using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().data('aClicked',true);
});
```

Then next time when you access div or click on a just check if has true or not.

Comment: Ahh. I understand what OP was asking now. My Bad.